# htaccess not rerouting index page to prerender.io cache (but reroutes subpages)

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, prerender

This works:
example.com/24

This does not:
example.com

I'm not sure if the problem in htaccess or in apache conf.

.htaccess code

```
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine on

            # Redirect www to non-www
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

            Options +FollowSymLinks
            #RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://vivule.ee/api/$1 [P,L]

            # Don't rewrite files or directories, but exclude adminer directory
            RewriteRule ^(adminer)($|/) - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
            RewriteRule ^ - [L]

            # Prerender.io stuff
            <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot|bingbot|Googlebot-Mobile|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|DoCoMo|Twitterbot|TweetmemeBot|Twikle|Netseer|Daumoa|SeznamBot|Ezooms|MSNBot|Exabot|MJ12bot|sogou\sspider|YandexBot|bitlybot|ia_archiver|proximic|spbot|ChangeDetection|NaverBot|MetaJobBot|magpie-crawler|Genieo\sWeb\sfilter|Qualidator.com\sBot|Woko|Vagabondo|360Spider|ExB\sLanguage\sCrawler|AddThis.com|aiHitBot|Spinn3r|BingPreview|GrapeshotCrawler|CareerBot|ZumBot|ShopWiki|bixocrawler|uMBot|sistrix|linkdexbot|AhrefsBot|archive.org_bot|SeoCheckBot|TurnitinBot|VoilaBot|SearchmetricsBot|Butterfly|Yahoo!|Plukkie|yacybot|trendictionbot|UASlinkChecker|Blekkobot|Wotbox|YioopBot|meanpathbot|TinEye|LuminateBot|FyberSpider|Infohelfer|linkdex.com|Curious\sGeorge|Fetch-Guess|ichiro|MojeekBot|SBSearch|WebThumbnail|socialbm_bot|SemrushBot|Vedma|alexa\ssite\saudit|SEOkicks-Robot|Browsershots|BLEXBot|woriobot|AMZNKAssocBot|Speedy|oBot|HostTracker|OpenWebSpider|WBSearchBot|FacebookExternalHit [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

                # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
                RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://vivule.ee/$2 [P,L]
            </IfModule>

            # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
            RewriteRule ^adminer - [L,NC]
            RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

        </IfModule>
```

I'm testing with this:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Problem webpage:
http://vivule.ee/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's how I solved it. It turns out the problem lies with Apache 2.4 setup, for some reason it bypasses prerender servers and serves raw html from original server. I got it solved by adding "DirectoryIndex" into the htaccess file. No parameters added, this sets the page index to http://example.com/.

Here is my final code:

```
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            DirectoryIndex
            RewriteEngine on

            # Redirect www to non-www
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

            Options +FollowSymLinks
            #RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://vivule.ee/api/$1 [P,L]


            # Prerender.io stuff
            <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Baiduspider|DoCoMo|Twitterbot|TweetmemeBot|Twikle|Netseer|Daumoa|SeznamBot|Ezooms|MSNBot|Exabot|MJ12bot|sogou\sspider|bitlybot|ia_archiver|proximic|spbot|ChangeDetection|NaverBot|MetaJobBot|magpie-crawler|Genieo\sWeb\sfilter|Qualidator.com\sBot|Woko|Vagabondo|360Spider|ExB\sLanguage\sCrawler|AddThis.com|aiHitBot|Spinn3r|BingPreview|GrapeshotCrawler|CareerBot|ZumBot|ShopWiki|bixocrawler|uMBot|sistrix|linkdexbot|AhrefsBot|archive.org_bot|SeoCheckBot|TurnitinBot|VoilaBot|SearchmetricsBot|Butterfly|Yahoo!|Plukkie|yacybot|trendictionbot|UASlinkChecker|Blekkobot|Wotbox|YioopBot|meanpathbot|TinEye|LuminateBot|FyberSpider|Infohelfer|linkdex.com|Curious\sGeorge|Fetch-Guess|ichiro|MojeekBot|SBSearch|WebThumbnail|socialbm_bot|SemrushBot|Vedma|alexa\ssite\saudit|SEOkicks-Robot|Browsershots|BLEXBot|woriobot|AMZNKAssocBot|Speedy|oBot|HostTracker|OpenWebSpider|WBSearchBot|FacebookExternalHit [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

                # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
                RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://vivule.ee/$2 [P,L]
            </IfModule>

            # Don't rewrite files or directories, but exclude adminer directory
            RewriteRule ^(adminer)($|/) - [L]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
            RewriteRule ^ - [L]

            # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
            RewriteRule ^adminer - [L,NC]
            RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

        </IfModule>
```

Comment: Dear Yodalr, I have a problem with how to know prerender is working! I have a  red error which say that "We haven't seen a request with your Prerender token yet.". I have to wait for a while or after setup my .htaccess file, it will be gone? It's good to mention that all 3 mode options in the server is enable! Thank you for helping me ASAP.

Comment: @Hamed, contact user prerender.io - https://stackoverflow.com/users/3450859/prerender-io he seems to be the dev of prerender

Answer (score -1):

This could be matching your homepage and serving the index.html from before the prerender config is run

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Try moving the prerender config higher up in your file.